# PHP - How can I return true if the value of the table A is on the same position(index) than the value of the table B?

Tags: php

I used the explode function and i'd like to do a test in order to know when the value of the table 1 is on the same index that the value of the table 2.

Example:

```
$pizza1  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$piecesA = explode(" ", $pizza1);

$pizza2  = "piece7 piece8 piece9 piece10 piece11 piece12";
$piecesB = explode(" ", $pizza2);
```

I can compare the values but not the position: I don't know how can I say within the foreach this: if the two values are in the same position (index) return true...

for example: piece1 and piece7 are in the same index. (the index 0 of each table)

Can you please explain me how can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by:  *values of two tables are in the same index*?

Comment: for example: piece1 and piece7 are in the same index. (the index 0 of each table) Thanks

Comment: @TimCooper, I believe he means if two arrays have the same element at a certain index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pizza1  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$piecesA = explode(" ", $pizza1);

$pizza2  = "piece7 piece8 piece9 piece10 piece11 piece12";
$piecesB = explode(" ", $pizza2);
foreach($piecesB as $key => $val){
    if($piecesB[$key]==$piecesA[$key]){
        //same val and key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function search( $arrayA, $arrayB, $item )
{
  $indexA = array_search($item, $arrayA);
  $indexB = array_search($item, $arrayB);

  return $indexA == $indexB;
}
```